# passing c++ double pointer to python

Tags: python, numpy, ctypes, cython, f2py

I could pass one-dimension array to python like below.
and I wonder if I can pass c++ double pointer array to python by using ctypes, numpy.

test.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" void cfun(const void * indatav, int rowcount, int colcount, void * outdatav);

void cfun(const void * indatav, int rowcount, int colcount, void * outdatav) {
    //void cfun(const double * indata, int rowcount, int colcount, double * outdata) {
    const double * indata = (double *) indatav;
    double * outdata = (double *) outdatav;
    int i;
    puts("Here we go!");
    for (i = 0; i < rowcount * colcount; ++i) {
        outdata[i] = indata[i] * 4;
    }
    puts("Done!");
}
```

test.py:

```
import numpy
import ctypes

indata = numpy.ones((5,6), dtype=numpy.double)
outdata = numpy.zeros((5,6), dtype=numpy.double)
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./ctest.so')
fun = lib.cfun
# Here comes the fool part.
#fun(ctypes.c_void_p(indata.ctypes.data), ctypes.c_void_p(outdata.ctypes.data))

fun(ctypes.c_void_p(indata.ctypes.data), ctypes.c_int(5), ctypes.c_int(6),
    ctypes.c_void_p(outdata.ctypes.data))


print 'indata: %s' % indata
print 'outdata: %s' % outdata
```

Comment: This is a hack I have been taught, but why not just pass the  pointers as long integers ?

Comment: because the type can be double.. etc not only integer.

Comment: The pointers can always be represented as long integers. and then cast back to whatever type you want.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a way.  I didn't see a nice way to use numpy with double**.

test.cpp (Windows)

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void cfun(const double ** indata, int rowcount, int colcount, double ** outdata) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colcount; ++j) {
            outdata[i][j] = indata[i][j] * 4;
        }
    }
}
```

test.py

```
import numpy
import ctypes

# Allocate array of double*
indata = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double) * 5)()
for i in range(5):
    # Allocate arrays of double
    indata[i] = (ctypes.c_double * 6)()
    for j in range(6):
        indata[i][j] = 1.0

outdata = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_double) * 5)()
for i in range(5):
    outdata[i] = (ctypes.c_double * 6)()
    for j in range(6):
        outdata[i][j] = 1.0

lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('test')
fun = lib.cfun

def dump(a,rows,cols):
    for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
            print a[i][j],
        print

dump(indata,5,6)
fun(ctypes.byref(indata),5,6,ctypes.byref(outdata))
dump(outdata,5,6)
```

Output

```
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0 4.0
```

Comment: I got an error while creating ".so" file
test.cpp:4:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Comment: it works fine without "__declspec(dllexport)". thanks and in fortran, multi-dimensional array can be passed directly with numpy right? fwrap.. actually I am looking for passing array among python <-> c,c++ <-> fortran.

Comment: Yes, `__declspec(dllexport)` is Windows-specific to export a function from a dynamic library.  The code you posted works as is (with minor mods for Windows, for me) with a double pointer and multi-dimensional array.  You don't need all that casting, though.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: I haven't touched Fortran for years so can't help there.  I'll note that if you write your original C++ function with `double*` instead of `void*` you can pass `_____.ctypes.data` directly without the `ctypes.c_void_p` wrappers.  You also can pass `5,6` instead of `ctypes.c_int(5),ctypes.c_int(6)`.

Comment: Is there a way to pass this array by using numpy? I want to use numpy not only using ctypes.

Comment: Not that I know of if you are forced to call an existing function that takes double**. You could write a conversion function to convert from a multi-dimensional numpy array to double**.